# image loop in carousel jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a carousel that animates to the right depending on the `li` width.
After reaching the end it keeps animating until the last image is the only one you see. With a blank space to the right. How would I set it to loop so there is no blank space and the first images appears again?
My move right jquery code.

```
            $('#right').click(function () {
            if (currentItem === totalItems) {
                $inner.animate({
                    right: '-=' + width * (totalItems-1) + 'px'
                }, speed);
                currentItem = 1;
            } else {
                $inner.animate({
                    right: '+=' + width
                }, speed);
                currentItem += 1;
            }
        });
```

So after getting to the end it rewinds to the first image.

**EDIT:** Here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8syDm/)** if you guys want to see.

Comment: You need to clone the first element and place it after the last, and keep doing that forever

Comment: So I would have to add the `.clone()` and remove the `right: '-=' + width * (totalItems-1) + 'px'`? Or how would I implement the `.clone()`?